# What is the correct preposition for "ask"?

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

While the verb "ask" is usually followed by an indirect object and therefore doesn't take a preposition, it is sometimes the case that we want to emphasize the person who is supposed to answer the question. For example, if we were to change the sentence "We asked Robert the same question" to a passive voice, which sentence would be correct?

A: "The same question was asked from Robert."

B: "The same question was asked to Robert."

C: "The same question was asked of Robert."

D: "???"

I also need to point out that we are talking about a question out of curiosity (such as "What would you do if you won the lottery?"), which I think rules out "of" and "for" since they are used for "favors and requests". Also, "by" is not what I'm looking for either. Robert is not asking the question. He is supposed to answer it.

Comment: Why do you think a question asked out of curiosity would rule out "of"?

Comment: Well, as I said, I think we use "of" to make or talk about "requests". Like "I have a favor I need to ask of you and your brother."

Comment: "Asked of" would be most idiomatic.

Comment: C: "The same questions were asked of Robert."

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks. There's no reason not to use "of" for questions that are not requests.

Comment: Yeah, C is wrong because of "questions was", not because of the preposition.

Comment: The passive voice chases all the party joy out of the classic *A good time was had by all*. In the same way, you may see that turning your clear sentence into a backward one is directly due to the passive voice. No preposition can completely correct the source of the problem.

Comment: See Gary Botnovcan's answer to a similar question on ELL: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/161238/the-meaning-of-asked-of-in-this-sentence

Comment: @Mark Hubbard - Correcting a correction. "The same *question was* asked of Robert." - This is correct because according to the OP, we only asked one question.

Comment: Since ask is a ditransitive (or bitransitive) verb, another passive is possible without a preposition: "Robert was asked the same question"